# If statement in javascript not responding to array elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

6 boxes are declared as array elements.

I assigned an `if` statement to alert *"correct"* if the box matching the RGB color of array[2] is clicked and an `else` statement to alert *"wrong"*  if it does not match the RGB color that is in array element[2].

Everything seems correct but now any colour I click alerts *"wrong"* which is not meant to be. Because box 3 which is contained in `[2]` is meant to alert *"correct"*.

Please help me out as I can figure out why it is not displaying *"correct"* even when I click on the right box which is assigned to `[2]`.

Please how do I go about 
 this help?

```js
// toggle button-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var click = document.querySelector('button')
function change () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('body')
}
click.addEventListener('click', change)

// grid coloursm------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var colors = [
  'rgb(255,0,0)',
  'rgb(255,255,0)',
  'rgb(25,0,255)',
  'rgb(25,255,203)',
  'rgb(250,0,0)',
  'rgb(0,255,100)',
]
// picked color****************************************************
var picked = colors[4]
var colourDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay')
colourDisplay.textContent = picked
 
// select grids****************************************************
var square = document.querySelectorAll('.square')

// add var colors to var square using array************************
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  // add initial listeners to square
  square[i].style.background = colors[i]
  // add clicked listeners to square 
  square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    if(clickedColor === picked){
      alert('correct');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #232323;
}

.body{
    background-color: rgb(45, 174, 206);
}

.square{
    width: 30%;
    background: chocolate;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#con{
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this game was developed by alabo -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Game project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> colour <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> color  game</h1>
<div id="con">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
    <button>click me</button>
    
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you debug why? `console.log(clickedColor, picked)`

Comment: It's `'rgb(250, 0, 0)'` not `'rgb(250,0,0)'` ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two variables do not have same string. The picked color is a RGB without space between digits and clicked color has a string with space. Javascript compares with each and every character. That's why it is failing.
Clicked color: "rgb(250, 0, 0)"
Picked : "rgb(250,0,0)".
Check this fiddle. I have modified your code. 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/c3rmLjgj/

Answer (score 4):

Well i found the issue in about 30 seconds by adding a console.log in the click event like this:

```
square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    console.log(clickedColor + ' VS ' + picked);
    if(clickedColor === picked){
      alert('correct');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
});
```

The result when clicking on the fourth box was `rgb(250, 0, 0) VS rgb(250,0,0)`.
So the problem is that the result of `this.style.background;` is `rgb(250, 0, 0)` while your array has the color defined as `rgb(250,0,0)`, notice the spacing. So simply fixing your colors array spacing will fix your issue.

And here is the working example:

```js
// toggle button-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var click = document.querySelector('button');
function change () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('body');
}
click.addEventListener('click', change);

// grid coloursm------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var colors = [
  'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  'rgb(25, 0, 255)',
  'rgb(25, 255, 203)',
  'rgb(250, 0, 0)',
  'rgb(0, 255, 100)',
];
// picked color****************************************************
var picked = colors[4];
var colourDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay');
colourDisplay.textContent = picked;
 
// select grids****************************************************
var square = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

// add var colors to var square using array************************
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  // add initial listeners to square
  square[i].style.background = colors[i] ;
  // add clicked listeners to square 
  square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    if(clickedColor === picked){
      alert('correct');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #232323;
}

.body{
    background-color: rgb(45, 174, 206);
}

.square{
    width: 30%;
    background: chocolate;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#con{
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- this game was developed by alabo -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Game project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> colour <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> color  game</h1>
<div id="con">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
    <button>click me</button>
    
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is easy to determine if you use some `console.log()`.
You will see that `this.style.background` contains more information and not only the background-color.

To solve this problem I've changed it to `this.style.backgroundColor` but that doesn't completly fix it. You have to remove the spacebars. I did that by using `this.style.backgroundColor.split(" ").join("")`

```js
// toggle button-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var click = document.querySelector('button')
function change () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('body')
}
click.addEventListener('click', change)

// grid coloursm------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var colors = [
  'rgb(255,0,0)',
  'rgb(255,255,0)',
  'rgb(25,0,255)',
  'rgb(25,255,203)',
  'rgb(250,0,0)',
  'rgb(0,255,100)',
]
// picked color****************************************************
var picked = colors[4]
var colourDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay')
colourDisplay.textContent = picked
 
// select grids****************************************************
var square = document.querySelectorAll('.square')

// add var colors to var square using array************************
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  // add initial listeners to square
  square[i].style.background = colors[i]
  // add clicked listeners to square 
  square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor.split(" ").join("");
    if(clickedColor == picked){
      alert('correct');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #232323;
}

.body{
    background-color: rgb(45, 174, 206);
}

.square{
    width: 30%;
    background: chocolate;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#con{
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this game was developed by alabo -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Game project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> colour <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> color  game</h1>
<div id="con">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
    <button>click me</button>
    
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problems in your spacing of `rbg(255,0,0)`. If you `console.log(this.style.background)` you'll notice that the value is `rgb(255, 0, 0)` with spaces after the `,`. I've also changed one of the values in `colors[]` from `rbg(250, 0, 0)` to `rbg(255, 0, 0)` since I think it's a typo.

```js
// toggle button-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var click = document.querySelector('button')
function change () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('body')
}
click.addEventListener('click', change)

// grid coloursm------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var colors = [
  'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
  'rgb(25, 0, 255)',
  'rgb(25, 255, 203)',
  'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  'rgb(0, 255, 100)',
]
// picked color****************************************************
var picked = colors[4]
var colourDisplay = document.getElementById('colorDisplay')
colourDisplay.textContent = picked
 
// select grids****************************************************
var square = document.querySelectorAll('.square')

// add var colors to var square using array************************
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  // add initial listeners to square
  square[i].style.background = colors[i]
  // add clicked listeners to square 
  square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;
    // console.log("Background: " + this.style.background);
    // console.log("Picked: " + picked);
    if(clickedColor === picked){
      alert('correct');
    } else {
      alert('wrong');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #232323;
}

.body{
    background-color: rgb(45, 174, 206);
}

.square{
    width: 30%;
    background: chocolate;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#con{
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1{
    color: cornsilk;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this game was developed by alabo -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Game project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="game.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1> colour <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> color  game</h1>
<div id="con">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
    <button>click me</button>
    
</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```